# Is it possible in Magento 2 to load content in between products?

Tags: magento2, category, product-collection, page-content

I'm wondering if it is possible at all to load some content (different per page) in between the product collection. I've made a module injecting some content that I enter in the backend, but obviously every page of my category now displays the same content blocks at the same place, since the product collection is just loaded a second time for the second page.

What I want is to be able to inject different content for the second, third page etc. I added some screenshots of how I would want it to be. Any help would be appreciated!
[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]

Answer (score 1):

Inserting varied content relevant to your page will be possible likely: 
for instance in the category page, I would write an afterplugin onto the function `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::getLoadedProductCollection`.

your plugin may get the data fetching the current category id and load a specific content from here with business rule you will have to define.

and then in the plugin you can add some items to the collection like below:

```
$object = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject //used to be Varien_Object in M1

$object->setData('id', uniqid());
$object->setData('type', 'cms');
$object->setData('html', $html);
```